# Scala: How to define an enum with extra attributes?

Tags: scala

I have a use-case where I need to define a new enum type `LongShort` but I need it in a way to also carry the sign so it can be directly used in mathematical expressions e.g.

```
object LongShortType extends Enumeration {
    type Type = Value
    val Long = Value(+1)
    val Short = Value(-1)
}
```

I'd then like to use it like this:

```
val longShort = LongShortType.Short 
val numberOfContracts: Int = 10
val vanillaOptionNotional: Double = longShort*numberOfContracts
```

but this leads to compiler error `cannot resolve symbol *` ... is there a way to extract the value of the enum? Or am I not understanding how enum types work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK I worked out a solution to accomplish what I wanted without any compromisse and by that I mean that this solution has all the advantages of using Scala enum e.g. the `withName` and still allows me to define extra features on it:

```
object LongShortType extends Enumeration {
  type Type = LongShortVal
  val Long = Value("Long", +1)
  val Short = Value("Short", -1)
  case class LongShortVal(name: String, sign: Int) extends Val(nextId, name)
  protected final def Value(name: String, sign: Int) = new LongShortVal(name, sign)
}
```

and now can do:

```
val longShort = LongShortType.Short 
val numberOfContracts: Int = 10
val vanillaOptionNotional: Double = longShort.sign*numberOfContracts
```

and can also do:

```
val longShort = LongShort.withName("Long") // returns LongShort.Long
```

Answer (score 1):

The type of `LongShortType.Short` isn't `Int`, it's `Value`. You can either extract the underlying id of the value:

```
val longShort = LongShortType.Short.id
```

Which is a little ugly. Or you could not use an enum type at all:

```
object LongShortType {
  val Long = 1
  val Short = -1 
}
```

And then your equation would work as is.